# Passing a value to a UIView returns nil

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController `GamePlayViewController` and a UIView `JoystickView`.

Im trying to set a float value to the `JoystickView`.

In `GamePlayViewController.m`

```
JoystickView *joystick = [[JoystickView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

joystick.velocity = 123.0f;
[self.view addSubview:joystick];
```

In `JoystickView.h`

```
@property(nonatomic) float velocity;
```

.m

```
@synthesize velocity;
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    NSLog(@"%f", velocity);        //output is 0
}
return self;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you are setting the velocity after init with frame was called

Comment: Ok i thought the initWithFrame would get called after the viewController added it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the initWithFrame by creating a initWithFrameAndVelocity method

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andVelocity:(float)v {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
velocity = v;
    NSLog(@"%f", velocity);        //output is 0
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: This is what seemed best and it worked, cant accept answer yet, but in 2 min i can ;)

Comment: This does not seem an answer to the question of passing a  So, if this is the answer you were looking for, I would suggest you to rewrite the question to ask for a way of setting a property to the value passed as a parameter to the initialization of a view.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of evaluating your `NSLog(@"%f", velocity);`, the `initWithFrame:` method has not finished executing, so the assignation `joystick.velocity = 123.0f` has not been executed yet (remember this is executed **sequentially**). That is why the value outputted by the NSLog is the default initialization value for a **float** (0).

You can solve this by **moving the `NSLog` right after the assignation**.

```
JoystickView *joystick = [[JoystickView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
joystick.velocity = 123.0f;
NSLog(@"%f", joystick.velocity); // prints 123.0
[self.view addSubview:joystick];
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the `velocity` property AFTER the `initWithFrame:` method, but your `NSLog` is inside `initWithFrame:`. At that point, velocity is not yet set

Answer (score 1):

put your

```
NSLog(@"%f", velocity);
```

after initWithFrame. As far as your app knows, velocity hasn't been initialized as 123.0f yet, hence it'll show as 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting velocity after initWithFrame is called. So the NSLog output is going to be 0.